# Windows forms: TreeView control with multiple columns

Tags: .net, treeview

Is there a way to have multiple columns in TreeView control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the standard TreeView does not allow columns, what you are looking for is commonly called a TreeListView. So you'll need a custom control.

There are many listed on CodeProject:

- [TreeListView User Control (Lite).](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeViewColumns.aspx)
- [TreeListView (Simple)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx)
- [The TreeListView To End All TreeListViews.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/WinControls_TreeListView.aspx?msg=2834181)

Personally I'd recomend [TreeViewAdv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/) on SourceForge

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can also think about a datagridview with treeview functionalities embedded:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx?PageIndex=6