# Adding custom control to visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, controls

There is a control uploaded online called ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl. I would like to upload this control into my existing visual studio project. I tried this using the simple "add existing item" method, however I was not able to edit the control for some reason. The control is not in the form of a dll or a EXE it is simply a visual basic project (.vb, .resx). How can I import this control into my visual studio project so that I can use it (and edit it) in my form? What are the steps?
Here is a link to the TreeViewMultiCtrl: http://www.g3nius.org/vbnet/ctrlTreeViewMultiCtrl.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: @HansPassant There is no vbproj file (only .vb, .resx, and .Designer.vb).

Comment: You need a .vbproj file, not much of a genius, is he?  Don't use crappy incomplete projects, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502627/windows-forms-treeview-control-with-multiple-colums).

Comment: Okay thanks! Is it okay that my project is in vb.net and those are written in C sharp?

Comment: Also I've tried uploading a few of these projects and I continue to get a message saying the variable is either undeclared or was never assigned. Many people recommend rebuilding and restarting the project, but this does not work for me. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: If you take C# code and compile it into a DLL you will be able to use it from VB.NET.

Comment: Great thanks that helps!